# Unsigned long long arithmetic into double

Tags: c++, geometry, double, trigonometry, unsigned-long-long-int

I'm making a function that takes in 3 unsigned long longs, and applies the law of cosines to find out if the triangle is obtuse, acute or a right triangle. Should I just cast the variables to doubles before I use them?

```
void triar( unsigned long long& r, 
            unsigned long long x, 
            unsigned long long y, 
            unsigned long long z ) 
{
  if(x==0 || y==0 || z==0) die("invalid triangle sides");

  double t=(x*x + y*y -z*z)/(2*x*y);

  t=acos (t) * (180.0 / 3.14159265);

  if(t > 90) {
    cout<<"Obtuse Triangle"<<endl;
    r=t;

  } else if(t < 90){
    cout<<"Acute Triangle"<<endl;
    r=t;

  } else if(t == 90){
    cout<<"Right Traingle"<<endl;
    r=t;

  }
}
```

Comment: Why does the function take in `unsigned long long` and not `double`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is generally no reason why you could not cast if you need floating point arithmetics.  However, there is also an implicit conversion from `unsigned long` to `double`, so  you can also often do completely without casting.

In many cases, including yours, you can cast only one of the arguments to force `double` arithmetics on a particular operation only.  For example,

```
double t = (double)(x*x + y*y - z*z) / (2*x*y)
```

This way, all operations except for the division are computed in integer arithmetics and are therefore slighly faster.  The cast is still necessary to avoid truncation during division.

Your code contains a comparison of floating point arguments. Floating point arithmetics however almost inevitably reduces accuracy.  Avoid limited accuracy, or analyze and control accuracy.

- Prefer an integer only solution as described in an excellent sister answer if you have a wide enough integral type at your disposal
- Always avoid conversion from radians to degrees except for presentation to humans
- Take the value of π from your mathematical library header files (unfortunately, this is platform dependent - try `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` + `M_PI` or, if already using boost libraries, `boost::math::constants::pi<double>()`), or express it analytically.  For example, `std::atan(1)*2` is the right angle.
- If you choose double precision, and the ultimate difference value is less than, say, `std::numeric_limits<double>::min() * 8`, you can probably not tell anything about the triangle and the classification you return is basically bogus.  (I made up the value of 8, you will possibly lose way more bits than three.)

Comment: hmmm I tried that earlier and it didn't seem to work. Now its working..... well thank you for your help anyway :)

Comment: @NimaGanjehloo - One possible explanation would be if you had extra parentheses around the whole division operation when it didn't work.  In that case you would have been casting the truncated result.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with obtuse triangles, `x*x + y*y - z*z` would mathematically give a negative result, that is then reduced modulo `2^WIDTH` (where `WIDTH` is the number of value bits in `unsigned long long`, at least 64 and probably exactly that) yielding a - probably large - positive value (or in rare cases 0). Then the computed result of `t = (x*x + y*y - z*z)/(2*x*y)` can be larger than 1, and `acos(t)` would return a NaN.

The correct way to find out whether the triangle is obtuse/acute/right-angled with the given argument type is to check whether `x*x + y*y < /* > / == */ z*z` - if you can be sure the mathematical results don't exceed the `unsigned long long` range.

If you can't be sure of that, you can either convert the variables to `double` before the computation,

```
double xd = x, yd = y, zd = z;
double t = (xd*xd + yd*yd - zd*zd)/(2*xd*yd);
```

with possible loss of precision and incorrect results for nearly right-angled triangles (e.g. for the slightly obtuse triangle `x = 2^29, y = 2^56-1, z = 2^56+2`, both `y` and `z` would be converted to 2^56 with standard 64-bit `double`s, `xd*xd + yd*yd = 2^58 + 2^112` would be evaluated to `2^112`, subtracting `zd*zd` then results in 0).

Or you can compare `x*x + y*y` to `z*z` - or `x*x` to `z*z - y*y` - using only integer arithmetic. If `x*x` is representable as an `unsigned long long` (I assume that `0 < x <= y <= z`), it's relatively easy, first check whether `(z - y)*(z + y)` would exceed `ULLONG_MAX`, if yes, the triangle is obtuse, otherwise calculate and compare. If `x*x` is not representable, it becomes complicated, I think the easiest way (except for using a big integer library, of course) would be to compute the high and if necessary low 64 (or whatever width `unsigned long long` has) bits separately by splitting the numbers at half the width and compare those.

Further note: Your value for π, `3.14159265` is too inaccurate, right-angled triangles will be reported as obtuse.